# how to start Apache Zeppelin server from a java client?

Tags: java, apache, apache-zeppelin

Is there a way that I could start Apache zeppelin server from a java client?

I checked the https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/server/ZeppelinServer.java file.

I guess the server is started within the main method of this file. If so how do I start the server from my java client?

Comment: just call that main method and pass the needed parameters.

Comment: Ah! I just thought I couldn't call the main method. Thanks